# opencv2/calib3d.hpp : No suh file or directory (How to link opencv to qt correcttly)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I installed opencv 3.4.0-dev and I want to use it with QT.
In the .pro I added :

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
```

but i still have the error
`opencv2/calib3d.hpp : No such file or directory`
(I also try with highgui, imgcedexs, core, same error)

Any idea to fix it ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I fixed it by adding INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4 but i still have the following error :

Comment: `opencv2/ximgproc/disparity_filter.hpp: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

As you've figured by yourself, the opencv header path is now nested in `/usr/local/include/opencv4`.

As for the error you've flagged in the comment, `ximgproc` is a contrib module and should be added manually. You therefore need to build OpenCV from source or find a pre-built package that has the contrib modules built in.

[This question](https://answers.opencv.org/question/174707/how-to-install-opencv-with-contrib-modules/) and [this OpenCV doc page](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) answers how to build OpenCV with the contrib modules.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing following:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-calib3d-dev
```